# jquery change content of page by clicking button on the second page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have 2 php files and one jquery file (2 php files include that jquery file). How to change content of 1 page by clicking button on the 2 page using jquery(without refreshing pages). for ex: on button click send div (2 page) to the div (1 page). OR maybe use 2 jquery files or any other techniques. code demonstration would be perfect. my code:
**ex2.php**

```
<script src="ex2.js"></script>
<title>Ex2</title>
</head>

<body>
<button class="show"> show </button>
<div class="showdiv"> show </div>
</body>
```

**ex3.php**

```
<script src="ex2.js"></script>
<title>Ex3</title>
</head>

<body>
<button class="save"> Save </button>
<div class="savediv"> Save </div>
</body>
```

**ex2.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".save").click(function() {
        $(".showdiv").after("<p>GGGGGGGG</p>");

    });
    $(".show").click(function() {
        $(".showdiv").after("<p>BBBBBBBB</p>");
        $(".savediv").after("<p>BBBBBBBB</p>");
    });

});
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What happened? Did you get errors? What did your research say? Generally in order to get answers here, you have to demonstrate your effort up to this point.

Comment: show button is working, while save button doesn't work, that is the problem

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this type of "push" is only possible when you have a highly complex system involving server-side services and hooks on the receiving pages that are listening for changes to those services. This question is accordingly too broad and probably too complicated for a simple answer, as per StackOverflow guidelines.

Comment: this isn't an answer...use comment blocks to post comments